# Moving a file from a React.JS frontend to a C++ backend

Tags: javascript, c++, reactjs, web, backend

So I have a function written in C++, that works on a file. I can convert it to a script and the script to take a parameter of the file location for example and work on it, that is not a problem.

My frontend is done with React, it is still not connected to the backend. I have a button that is "Upload File" the user clicks, and I need to have this file on my backend to run the C++ code on it.

Theoretically, the way I thought of (Not sure if it works):

1. User chooses the file to upload
2. From the frontend, we upload it to a cloud storage such as Google Drive for example
3. Then, from the Frontend I send an HTTP request using a REST API, with parameter as the file direct download link.
4. Then the REST API runs a Python function that executes the following shell commands:

> `wget (link that we got from the HTTP request through REST API`

And after that the python script runs the C++ function on the file, and returns the output through the HTTP request.

Does that make sense?
Is there an easier or better way?

Thanks

Comment: Upload the file to the backend. Why do you want to upload it to Google Drive?

Comment: Yeah like @ThomasSablik said you should sent the file directly to the backend via form-data and then let the backend upload it to bucket style cloud storage if needed.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  Thanks a lot for your replies. Could you please elaborate a little bit on this? Is a REST API not needed in this case? If there's an article you know that might help I'd be happy to read.

Comment: @YacineMahdid Thanks a lot for your replies. Could you please elaborate a little bit on this? Is a REST API not needed in this case? If there's an article you know that might help I'd be happy to read.

Comment: Your backend has to implement some kind of API. It can be a REST API. How would you serve the frontend?

Comment: @JeriesHaddad I've written up an answer that explain a bit what are your options here, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Have the user load a file -> have the C++ function run on that file -> return output to the user.

### Possible Solution with REST-API

As you stated in your question you could upload to google drive and then wget the file, however its a bit too complex for nothing. What you could do instead is skip the uploading to the Google drive and directly send the file through formdata.

Here is a working example in React taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/AshikNesin/e44b1950f6a24cfcd85330ffc1713513):

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios, { post } from 'axios';

class SimpleReactFileUpload extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      file:null
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
  }
  onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
    this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);
    })
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({file:e.target.files[0]})
  }
  fileUpload(file){
    const url = 'http://example.com/file-upload';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return  post(url, formData,config)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
   )
  }
}
```

#### Possible Other Solution with AWS Lambda

For your specific use case I would not recommend having a full-blown REST-API, you could simply use a event-driven lambda function like [AWS Lambda](https://cloudacademy.com/lab/introduction-aws-lambda/?ads_cmpid=10049485382&ads_adid=96400038410&ads_matchtype=b&ads_network=g&ads_creative=435303054639&utm_term=&ads_targetid=dsa-898576037465&utm_campaign=&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&ttv=2&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI24aVuJPm6QIVhIbACh0ZDwwHEAAYAiAAEgINsPD_BwE). This way you only need to upload to Google Drive or S3 bucket and then the Lambda will run and generate an output which can be returned to the user.